# List array items with two colors, equal elements with same color in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have array of objects:

```
let objects = [
{
    id: 1,
    user_id: 2
},
{
    id: 2,
    user_id: 2
},
{
    id: 3,
    user_id: 3
},
{
    id: 4,
    user_id: 4
},
{
    id: 5,
    user_id: 4
},
{
    id: 6,
    user_id: 5
},
{
    id: 7,
    user_id: 4
},
];
```

i want to map through of it and give each other colors: red or blue. first two items will have blue, item with id 3 will have color red, next two items will have color blue, item with id 6 will have red and next item with id 7 will have color blue. so i just want  to save same items with `user_id` with same color but next items with same `user_id` must have second color. and i want this to be done in React.js jsx

```
{objects.map((x, i) => (
    <>{objects[i-1] !== undefined && objects[i+1] !== undefined && objects[i].user_id !== objects[i-1].user_id && objects[i].user_id !== objects[i+1].user_id }</>
))}
```

Comment: @TamirAbutbul I am checking if user_id-s of next and previous element equals of current item and [i-1] is not undefined then its blue else its red but it only works when there is no more that 3 same elements in order.

Comment: Don't do it by looking at x items in either direction, just check if the value changed between the current record, and the previous one. If so, it is time to toggle your color to the other alternative.

Comment: @CBroe i dont have this value in object. i just have user_id-s and what you saying does not work. already tried that. if it was just javascript then it would be simple, but in jsx i have no idea what to do. like, to have some variable inside html for toggling?

Answer (score 0):

You have to first find the duplicates and then you can apply condition ,
I have just done some code , you can see or make it better according to your work .

```js
  // find duplicates in collection
const duplicateCollection=(userIds)=>{
  const duplicates = [];
  const uniqueUserIds = new Set();
  userIds.forEach(userId => {
    if (uniqueUserIds.has(userId)) {
      duplicates.push(userId);
    } else {
      uniqueUserIds.add(userId);
    }
  });
  return duplicates;
}


 const toggleColorOnDifferentUserId=()=>{
  // simplify array by creating new array os users id only 
  const tempUsersId=objects.map(val=>val.user_id);
  const duplicateItems=duplicateCollection(tempUsersId);
  
  objects.map((val,i)=>{
    if(duplicateItems.includes(val.user_id)){
      console.log(i,"blue")
    }else{
      console.log(i,"red")
    }
  })
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use global variables to handle this, I have created a sample code for you through online compiler, it will fairly help you achieve what you want.

```
let objects = [
{
    id: 1,
    user_id: 2
},
{
    id: 2,
    user_id: 2
},
{
    id: 3,
    user_id: 3
},
{
    id: 4,
    user_id: 4
},
{
    id: 5,
    user_id: 4
},
{
    id: 6,
    user_id: 5
},
{
    id: 7,
    user_id: 4
},
{
    id: 7,
    user_id: 4
},
{
    id: 7,
    user_id: 5
},
{
    id: 7,
    user_id: 4
},
];

let color="blue";
let item=objects[0].user;
let resetColor=true


objects.map((data)=> {
    if(data.user_id===item){
      color="blue"
      resetColor=false
     }else{
      color= resetColor ?"blue" :"red"
      resetColor=true
   }
    console.log(color)
      item=data.user_id
    
  } )
```

This will console log your desired condition, in the compiler. And if you are getting confused about how can you use it in **jsx**, you can try something like this:

```
      {objects.map((data) => {
    if (data.user_id === item) {
      color = "blue";
      resetColor = false;
    } else {
      color = resetColor ? "blue" : "red";
      resetColor = true;
    }
    console.log(color);
    item = data.user_id;
    return <div></div>;
  })}
```

This will create extra divs in your htmlbut will get the work done, it sure can be made more sensible if I know more about what you want to create. However this should be enough to give you the idea about how it can be done and you can change it to your needs. e.g maybe instead of console.log(), you may wanna change color though setState.